# How to change dynamically an html attribute with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

There is a simple way to change dynamically an html attribute?
I hide a div with angular scope variable and a `ng-hide`, but the size of the div still there,  how I can change the size of that `div`?

I tried  with: 
 `<div id="bodyContent" ng-hide="showContent" style="height:size"></div>`

and

`<div id="bodyContent" ng-hide="showContent" style="height:{{size}}"></div>`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: what is the problem? a hidden element has no height

Answer (score 1):

You must use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle#!)

```
<div id="bodyContent" ng-hide="showContent" ng-style="{'height':size}"></div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSPvs5J9Dk5iWEWzPoaZ?p=preview)

Comment: nothing saves you have to, works using style also http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmoWbhSIDj502Dqp3fhh?p=preview ..may not be practical but it does work